# Change bar width ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the width of the bars in the chart in the code below, using the `width`. However, I have not been successful. Can you help me?

The data used:

| Analises | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Correlation | 3 |
| Mathematical models | 4 |
| Posteriori test | 6 |
| Multivariate hypothesis testing | 17 |
| Univariate hypothesis testing | 29 |

The code used:

```
grafico5=ggplot(analises, aes(x= reorder(Analises, +Total), y= Total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,30), breaks = seq(0,30,5)) +
  coord_flip()+ xlab("Statistical analysis") + ylab("Number of articles") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 16, family= "sans", face= "bold"), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 16, family= "sans", face= "bold")) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 14, family= "sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 14, family= "sans"), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"))+ 
  geom_col(fill = gray(.3))
```

Comment: I don't see any `width` in your code. How are you trying? And why do you have a `geom_bar` and 2 `geom_col`s? Shouldn't 1 be enough? Maybe if you shared a little sample data your problem would be clearer.

Comment: By the way, if you set `axis.title = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 16, family= "sans", face= "bold")` then it will work for both `axis.title.x` and `axis.title.y`. Similarly for `axis.text`.

Comment: I can't run it without data but while you're putting some up, I could suggest having a try also with the ```width()``` argument inside ```position_dodge```. I'm not sure what you're trying to do and whether you want to keep the overall width of all bars together or manipulate the individual width, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are successfully changing the width of the `geom_bar()`, but then on top you are plotting the same thing at the default width with `geom_col()`, twice. If we delete your `geom_col()` lines it works:

```
ggplot(analises, aes(x= reorder(Analises, +Total), y= Total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,30),breaks = seq(0,30,5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Statistical analysis") + ylab("Number of articles")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(analises, aes(x= reorder(Analises, +Total), y= Total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.25) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,30),breaks = seq(0,30,5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Statistical analysis") + ylab("Number of articles")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I succeeded.